# Save knitr::kable() output to html file R

Tags: r, knitr

I have a knitr_kable output that I want to save as an HTML document from R. I need this to run automatically from my R script with no human involvement. For example:

```
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
kable(dt, "html") %>% kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"))
```

This has html output but the class is `knitr_kable` so I can't write it to a table or html file because it cannot be coerced to a dataframe.

```
class(kable(dt, "html"))
[1] "knitr_kable"
```

Does anyone have a method for saving one of these kables as an html file?

---

I've tried:

```
library(xml2)
options(knitr.table.format = "html") 
write_html(kable(dt, "html"), "df.html")))
```

This has error:

> Error in UseMethod("write_html") :    no applicable method for
>   'write_html' applied to an object of class "knitr_kable"

---

My guess would be that the knitr_kable object must first be coerced to an html object and then saved as html file. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `cat` function will do what you need.

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(magrittr)

dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]

kable(dt, "html") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover")) %>%
  cat(., file = "df.html")
```

The resulting table looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Why no striping?

Comment: This solution does not preserve the lines in my HTML table, which are visible in R

Answer (score 8):

### Save as HTML within your R script

The `readr` package has a `write_file` function that will write data "as it is", so HTML in the case of what you are creating with `knitr::kable`.

```
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
kable_out <- knitr::kable(dt, "html") %>% kableExtra::kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"))
readr::write_file(kable_out, "kable_out.html")
```

#### Alternatively: Save as temp.Rmd in R Studio

If you save the following as an R Markdown file (e.g., temp.Rmd) in R Studio, you can create the HTML by clicking Knit at the top-left center of RStudio.

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
```

## Table 1

```{r table1, echo = FALSE}
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
knitr::kable(dt, "html") %>% kableExtra::kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"))
```
````

## Click Knit in R Studio

[image]

Comment: The only thing is that I need this to run automatically from my R script with no human involvement.

Comment: I added a solution I believe you will find agreeable to the top of my answer, @jchaykow.