# how to combine multiple html (kable) tables into one image?

Tags: r, knitr, kable

I would like to combine several `kable` tables into one single image.
Something like:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:4]

# first table
table1 <- kable(dt, format = "html", caption = "Demo Table") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped",
                full_width = F) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 2, "Group 2[note]" = 2)) %>%
  add_footnote(c("table footnote"))

# second table
table2 <- kable(dt, format = "html", caption = "Demo Table") %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped",
                full_width = F) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "Group 1" = 2, "Group 2[note]" = 2)) %>%
  add_footnote(c("table footnote"))
```

and put `table1` on top of `table2` in an image:

```
bind_rows(table1, table2) %>% 
  kable_as_image(., filename = 'P:/mytable/table')
```

However, this does not work. How can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257488/save-knitrkable-output-to-html-file-r), it looks like the function cat could work to combine multiple tables into html. So you could do `kable(c(table1, table2), "html") %>% cat(., file = "P:/mytable/table.html")` And then convert the html to a jpg